# Bind List's cell property to an Observable ViewModel

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List, that its cells' content is bound to a model. The model content is fetched from web. I use the @StateObject + @ObservableObject + @Published mechanism to apply binding as follows:

ViewModel is:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var employees = [Employee]()
}
```

View is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PresentView: View {
   
   @StateObject var viewModel = PresenterViewModel("https://www.somelink.com/")
   
   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           List(self.viewModel.employees) { employee in
               EmployeeView(name: employee.name,
                            role: employee.title.rawValue)
           }
           .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
           .onAppear() {
               viewModel.load() // URL combine fetch
           }
           .navigationBarTitle("Company")
       }
   }
}

struct EmployeeView: View {
   
   var name: String   // <---- I want to attribute it a @Binding
   var role: String   // <---- I want to attribute it a @Binding

   var body: some View {
       HStack {
           Image(imageName)
           VStack {
               Text("\(name)")
                   .font(.headline)
               Text("\(role)")
                   .font(.subheadline)
           }
       }
   }
}
```

('Employee' carries a few strings and a enum and complies to Identifiable and Decodable)

My question:

Why can't I declare the properties of EmployeeView as @Binding? (it shouts: "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Binding" I guess he is expecting a "@State" from the caller but I can't supply that here).
After all it makes sense to apply the @Binding: I already have a source of truth and a two way binding in my view model. If I leave EmployeeView's with no @Binding, it means each cell content will be copied for each List load, and that's redundant, since I already have the source of truth in my model.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since `EmployeeView` doesn't modify anything, why do you need it to be a `Binding`?

Answer (score 1):

> After all it makes sense to apply the @Binding: I already have a source of truth and a two way binding in my view model.

That's not a correct way of thinking about it. You don't need a binding if the child view isn't modifying the content. Yes, the data would be copied, but that doesn't break the source of truth - the source of truth is still the view model, regardless of how many ***immutable*** copies there are.

---

But if the child view was modifying the content, then you'd need to annotate the properties it modifies with `@Binding`, and you need to pass a `Binding<String>` to them. Right now you're passing the `String` directly - hence the error.

Binding a list item is kinda wonky (in my opinion) in SwiftUI. There are multiple approaches you could take. One of them is to iterate on indices, instead of elements, of an array and use `$employees[index]` to get the binding to an element.

I would also suggest passing an entire `employee` object to `EmployeeView` instead of its individual properties.

```
List(self.viewModel.employees.indices, id: \.self) { index in
   EmployeeView(employee: self.$viewModel.employees[index])
}
```

Then, you need to use `@Binding` on the properties of `EmployeeView`:

```
struct EmployeeView: View {
   @Binding var employee: Employee

   var body: some View {
      VStack {
         TextField("", text: $employee.name) // ex: modifies the name
         Text(employee.role) // ex: doesn't modify the role
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Dear New Dev Thanks for your input, I like the idea of passing the whole object as reference. And yes, it doesn’t show on code but I plan to change the content in the future so your solution might work just fine. 10X